# Как вывести из бд с помощью PHP описание товара в нужном формате и с нужными стилями?

Tags: php, база-данных, вывод, формат

уважаемые эксперты! Добавил описание товара в ячейку таблицы phpmyadmin, вместе с картинкой, которая его иллюстрирует..

Не понимаю, как устроить вывод описание, чтобы оно приобретало нужное форматирование.. размер шрифта, расположение блока.. Пытался оборачивать в дивы echo, вводить html в сам текст после оператора.. ничего не получается.. Буду благодарен за любую помощь! Описание - это $result['discript'] из кода ниже..

```
$sql = "SELECT id, img, discript FROM pl ORDER BY id";
$sth = $connection->query($sql);
while ($result=$sth->fetch_array()) {
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['img'] ).'"/>';
echo $result['id'];
echo $result['log']. '<br />';
echo $result['discript'] . '<hr />';
```

Comment: Извините, я правильно понял, что вы чистый html код сохраняете в БД в ячейку `$result['discript']`? И кстати в какую БД?

Comment: База данных MySQL. Сохраняю просто в ячейке varchar описание.. просто текст (без html) Скрипт PHP благополучно его выводит под картинкой $result['img'], но без всякого форматирования.. А я бы хотел задать тексту стили, может быть, поставить ссылку в него ввести, задать расположение слева от картинки..

Comment: Я хотел добавить html в скрипт php, но столкнулся с тем, что, похоже у while нет альтернативного синтаксиса.. , а когда я ввожу div под оператор echo и создаю для него таблицу стилей, то стили не работают..

Comment: ну..вы вправе обернуть свой текст в какой угодно `div`, например. `echo '<div class="">'.$result['discript'].'</div>` или там `span` любой. А вот вставить внутрь этого текста, что либо еще, во время вывода его скриптом..Тут не подскажу. Легче сразу в базу сохранять уже со ссылкой.

Comment: А зачем вам альтернативный синтаксис?